# Polymer property not in element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

My Code:

```
<custom-x xy-user='online'></custom-x>
```

Element:

```
...
<div class='{{xyUser}}'></div>
...

Polymer({
    is: 'custom-x',

    properites: {
        xyUser: String
    }
});
```

But if i run the code and inspect it, the only thing i see is:

```
<div class='style-scope custom-x'></div>
```

I want to see the **online** as class. How is this possible...

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<div class$='{{xyUser}}'></div>
```

the `$=` is for data binding.

Comment: `$=` is for attribute binding,  `=` is for property binding, `{{}}` and `[[]]` for data binding.